# How do I set up 2 MySQL databases in Play Framework?

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean

I need to set up 2 separate databases. One for class Test and the other for class TestTwo, but I don't know how to configure the application.conf file.

application.conf (part 1):

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbone?characterEncoding=UTF-8" 

db.dbtwo.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
db.dbtwo.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtwo?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Failed attempt 1: both classes get saved to database 1 (dbone):
application.conf (part 2):

```
ebean.default="*"
ebean.dbtwo="models.TestTwo"
```

Failed attempt 2: I get an error when trying to save something:

```
[PersistenceException: The type [class models.TestTwo] is not a registered entity? If you don't explicitly list the entity classes to use Ebean will search for them in the classpath. If the entity is in a Jar check the ebean.search.jars property in ebean.properties file or check ServerConfig.addJar().]
```

application.conf (part 2):

```
ebean.default="models.Test"
ebean.dbtwo="models.TestTwo"
```

How can I set things up so Test objects are saved to dbone and TestTwo objects to dbtwo?

EDIT: TestTwo class as requested (nothing special; I didn't assign an Ebean server manually, other than in the application.conf file):

```
package models;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

@Entity
public class TestTwo extends Model{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Required
    public String testString;

    public static Model.Finder<Long, TestTwo> find = new Model.Finder<Long, TestTwo>(Long.class, TestTwo.class);

    public static TestTwo create (String testString){
        TestTwo test = new TestTwo();
        test.testString = testString;
        test.save();
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show some more code, especially the one used for saving entities.

Comment: The config looks ok, it's probably something in your code. I am not entirely sure if you can specify the database for each class, I've only used it for packages. You may want to try this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this question was the only relevant topic I could find about it anywhere. What I did to resolve it was not very pretty, but I made all of my model classes that are part of the non-default ebean server override the `save()`-, `delete()`- and `update()`-methods. These overrides respectively call `super.save(dbname)`, `super.delete(dbname)` and `super.update(dbname)`, where `dbname` is the name of the ebean server.

On startup, I pull the names out of the config and save them so they aren't hard-coded. Although it seems very redundant, it fixed the problem for me. I hope it helps someone else who wanders into this issue years later like I did!

Answer (score 0):

Did you write the evolution script? If not you need to write one in `conf>evolutions>default>1.sql`

Creating table 'testtwo':

```
create table testtwo(
    id          bigint auto_increment not null,
    testString      varchar(100) not null,
    constraint t1_testTwo primary key(id)
);
```

Further:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

drop table if exists testto;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

When you refresh the browser, play will ask to "apply evolution", this will create 'testtwo' table in your DB where you can save entities.